# How do I log output message from console in Linux?

Tags: linux, console

I am running a program under console.
It keep outputting debug messages on screen. 
If do like this,

```
$./myProgram >> log.txt
```

then I cannot see the debug message on screen, all the messages are going to the log.txt.

So, how do I log the messages into log.txt and show the debug message on screen as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're logging to stdout:

`$./myProgram | tee log.txt`

**EDIT**
If you choose to log errors to *`stderr`* then it might be useful to call you prog like this (*stderr* goes to one file, *stdout* goes to another file and to screen):

`$./myProgram 2>error_log.txt | tee output_log.txt`

Answer (score 1):

tee. (Now a bunch of characters to make the 30 character limit)